# How can I get a value from object in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following, how can I get the value for `shape` from the object to a variable?

```
var data = 
[
    {
        "Category": "Color",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Key": "color",
                "Value": "red"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Category": "Shape",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Key": "shape",
                "Value": "circle"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var shape = // want this to be 'circle'
```

Comment: Use array `find()`

Comment: See [many existing questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+get+a+value+from+object+in+an+array?+jquery+site:stackoverflow.com) on this.

Comment: `var shape = data[1].Options[0].Value;` that will return you circle. Structure of array is a bit complicated tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need the whole object you can use `find` or you can use `reduce` to get just what you need or you can get all the options with flatMap and than find the option you need

```js
var data = 
[
    {
        "Category": "Color",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Key": "color",
                "Value": "red"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Category": "Shape",
        "Options": [
            {
                "Key": "shape",
                "Value": "circle"
            }
        ]
    }
];

const shape = data.find(d => d.Category === 'Shape')

const shapeOption = data.reduce((res, d) => {
  if(d.Category === 'Shape'){
    return d.Options.find(o => o.Key === 'shape').Value
  }
  return res
}, null)

const shapeWithTransformations = data.flatMap(d => d.Options).find((o) => o.Key === 'shape').Value


console.log(shape)

console.log(shapeOption)
console.log(shapeWithTransformations)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will be

```js
var data = 
[
  {
      "Category": "Color",
      "Options": [
          {
              "Key": "color",
              "Value": "red"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "Category": "Shape",
      "Options": [
          {
              "Key": "shape",
              "Value": "circle"
          }
      ]
  }
];

const shape = data[1]['Options'][0]['Value'];
console.log(shape);
```

But your structure is over complicated, if you have control over it then it should be something like

```js
const data = 
{
    'Color': {
      'Key': 'color',
      'Value': 'red'
    },
    'Shape': {
      'Key': 'shape',
      'Value': 'circle'
    }
};

const shape = data['Shape']['Value'];
console.log(shape);
```

Comment: lol your 1st snippet is not working because it's missing the data array